# ConstraintLayout - center TextView in the root but don't override Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

So my application supports different languages and I can't predict how long will be title `TextView`. I want to have back `Button` on the same line but I want to prevent Text to cover the button. There's an example what I mean:

[image: example]

What's wrong with that:

[image]

What I want to achieve: when text will "meet" button, it should be spread out to two lines. I've tried barriers but then I can't center `TextView` in parent View and also auto-sizing text for button(this button could be `TextView` with enabled `clickOn`) but as you know it works only for API 26+, I need to support lower Android versions.

Is there way to achieve both: create `Barrier` to separate `Button` and `TextView` and also keep `TextView` in the middle of screen(not center between button and end of the screen)?

Comment: why not constrain the textview start to the end of the button and make the textview multiline?

Comment: If the TextView will start at the end of the button then I won't be able to center it in parent(center of the screen) but it will be centered between Button and the end of screen.

Comment: sorry, I didn't read that through, glad you have a workaround now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just think of a quick resolve for this.

You can create one more Button with the same size as your Back button. And align it to the right of the screen, with attribute `visibility="invisible`. Then make your TextView's width match with the 2 buttons.

Then your problem solved ! But make sure to change the additional button's attributes when ever you change your button's attributes

Comment: @Denathan I don't understand this. ***Then make your TextView's width match with the 2 buttons.*** 
can you please explain this furthur?

Comment: @Prashant added an answer below, hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @Denathan for explaining :D sorry for my bad English

Comment: @Denathan thanks for explaining. What i understood was from question was that `TextView` will remain in center if text in it is just a word but if it is a long line it won't overlap on `Button` on the left but will stretch to the right of the screen. that's why i was confused with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

**For further help.**

So to sum up what we've got to do based on @Sơn Phạm answer.

We need to create a mirror of the `Button` on the opposite side:
[image]

`TextView` should start at the end of left `Button` and end at start of the right `Button`:
[image]

You need to set `TextView` width as `match_constraint`. Nextly you need to set right button `android:visibility="invisible"`(not gone!) and make it unclickable. Now, we've got what we wanted to achieve:
[image]

**IMPORTANT**: Set the same string source for both buttons because when you support different languages your text button will change(e.g. en "Back", es "Regreso") but you want to keep both buttons same width. When you set button text source for both, for example `@string/back` both buttons will scale automatically.

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="@string/back"
    ... />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="@string/back"
    ... />
```

NOTE: It also works well with `Barrier`s.